# Binding Not Updating - Detecting Panel Children Added

Tags: silverlight, binding, panel, dependency-properties

I am currently implementing a Layout Conainer that inherits from `Panel` and is able to detect a change in `Panel.Children`, and detect the new element/deleted element.

At the moment, I've got a Dependency Property that is bound to the `Panel.Children.Count` value, which is terribly clunky, but I don't know a better way of creating such listeners.

```
public abstract class MyLayoutContainer : Panel
{
    private Binding countBinding;

    // ctor...

    private void InitializeBinding()
    {
        countBinding = new Binding("Count");
        countBinding.Source = this.Children;
        // Using the comment below instead of "Count"
        // in the Binding constructor throws an error
        //countBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(UIElementCollection.CountProperty);
        countBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, MyLayoutContainer.BoundChildCountProperty, countBinding);
    }

    // ...

    private static readonly DependencyProperty BoundChildCountProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register
        (
            "BoundChildCount",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(MyLayoutContainer),
            new PropertyMetadata(0, ChildCountChange)
        );

    private static int GetBoundChildCount(MyLayoutContainer depObj)
    {
        return (int)depObj.GetValue(BoundChildCountProperty);
    }
    private static void SetBoundVisibility(MyLayoutContainer depObj, int value)
    {
        depObj.SetValue(BoundChildCountProperty, value);
    }


    private static void ChildCountChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyLayoutContainer mlc = d as MyLayoutContainer;

        // For testing, this function is currently empty
        // however normally it checks children against a
        // shadow list, or will remove them as they're
        // added.
        mlc.ChildrenChanged(e.OldValue, e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it is only updating once.  It's almost as though I've set `BindingMode.OneTime` which is not the case.  When I check the `BoundChildCountProperty` against `this.Children.Count` I get 1 and 4.  I have no idea what's going on, because I've used this exact same method for binding to the visibility of another object to create a 'listener'.

Furthermore, I get much better functionality out of it in the XAML Designer (so many annoying MessageBoxes when I've got them in there...) when it's loading all the objects.

Please, if anyone knows a better way of doing this, or can see what I've done wrong, I will be very, very grateful!

**EDIT - Further Information:**
My end goal is to create a flexible class that can extended any of the current Panel classes (such as Grids and StackPanels) and because they seal the override functions I was hoping to find a workaround for detecting the children added, etc.

Comment: While this problem has not been solved directly, the solution proposed by AnthonyWJones below is a satisfactory work-around for those in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be overriding the methods `ArrangeOverride` and `MeasureOverride`, these are where you do your custom layout.  They will be called for various reasons one being whenever the `Children` membership changes.

Comment: @AWJ Thanks for the answer, however... Part of the issue is that I want to create an extended Grid class, and because of the rather frustrating 'sealed' modifier in C#, I can't override these functions in a sub-class.
At the moment, I'm dynamically creating a member of the base panel type (StackPanel, Grid, Canvas, etc) and trying to move the children added to this class to the member class.  Fiddly, but I don't see a way around it.

Comment: @Melodatron:  In that case why use a derivative of Panel at all?  Just start with a plain custom control that has a `Panel` as a required `TemplatePart`.  Implement your own `Children` property using a collection type you can control and forward members to the inner `Panel` in the manner you see fit.

Comment: @AWJ I'll give that a go and get back to you.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Melodatron:  Just one Caveat, you wouldn't be able to use such a custom control where a `Panel` is requried such as an ItemsControl ItemsPanel template.

Comment: While it doesn't *solve* the problem as such, it is a satisfactory work-around that I hadn't fully explored. It's just so frustrating that the binding doesn't work properly!